# column header in excel file with Perl

Tags: perl, excel

I have an Excel file with many columns, but I only need to do some calculations on 3 of those columns.

I'm using `SpreadSheet::ParseExcel` to iterate through my Excel file.  How do I specify which column I want with perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book1.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my @columns = (1,5,6) # enter your 3 columns here

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col (@columns) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            # do the calculations here
            print "Row, Col    = ($row, $col)\n";
            print "Value       = ", $cell->value(),       "\n";
            print "Unformatted = ", $cell->unformatted(), "\n";
            print "\n";
            # operations done
        }
    }
}
```

Source: Documentation of [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aParseExcel) module.

Comment: But isn't there a way to get their names rather than their numbers?

Comment: for that get the value of that cell.

Comment: read the header row, make a hash of names to column numbers, then in the data rows, get_cell($row, $col_for_header{'SomeHeader'})

Comment: Almost identical code here: [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm).  If the code's adapted, why not cite its source?

Comment: @Kenosis: Yes I took it from the official documentation so that it'll be easy for the OP to understand. I forgot to add the source there, I've edited the answer now which includes the source.